# Django Blog url error NoReverseMatch at /

Tags: django, django-urls

I git this error home.html page when I but the url to user posts page the url is work fine in other pages
but in home page I get this error

Reverse for 'user-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P[^/]+)/$']

I don't know if their something I need to but in home.html to let me access the post.author.usernname

home.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Blog Home!</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <img class = "rounded-circle article-img" src = "{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
            <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if is_paginated %}

        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a class = "btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
            <a class = "btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>  
        {% endif %}

        {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                <a class = "btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-4' and num < page_obj.number|add:'4' %}
                <a class = "btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a class = "btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
            <a class = "btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>  
        {% endif %}


    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView, 
    PostDetailView, 
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    UserPostListView
)
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name= "blog-home"),
    path('user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name= "user-posts"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name= "post-detail"),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name= "post-create"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name= "post-update"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name= "post-delete"),
    path('about/', views.about, name= "blog-about"),
]
```

the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView, 
    DetailView, 
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .models import Post

def home(request):
    content = {
        'posts':Post.objects.all()
    }    
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', content)

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username = self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author = user).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

the models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs = {'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: Please show your model for posts and your view `PostListView`.

Comment: Do you use this url in `blog/base.html` (you extend this template) somewhere?

Comment: no I don't needed their